# Multiprocess Queue synchronization with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.7

I want to gather data from `asyncio` loops running in sibling processes with Python 3.7

Ideally I would use a `multiprocess.JoinableQueue`, relaying on its `join()` call for synchronization.

However, its synchronization primitives **block the event loop in full** (see my partial answer below for an example).

Illustrative prototype:

```
class MP_GatherDict(dict):
    '''A per-process dictionary which can be gathered from a single one'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = multiprocess.JoinableQueue()
        super().__init__()

    async def worker_process_server(self):
        while True:
            (await?) self.q.put(dict(self)) # Put a shallow copy
            (await?) self.q.join() # Wait for it to be gathered

    async def gather(self):
        all_dicts = []
        while not self.q.empty():
            all_dicts.append(await self.q.get())
            self.q.task_done()
        return all_dicts
```

Note that the `put->get->join->put` flow might not work as expected but this question really is about using `multiprocess` primitives in `asyncio` event loop...

The question would then be **how to best `await` for `multiprocess` primitives from an asyncio event loop?**

Answer (score 1):

This test shows that `multiprocess.Queue.get()` blocks the whole event loop:

```
mp_q = mp.JoinableQueue()
async def mp_queue_wait():
    try:
        print('Queue:',mp_q.get(timeout=2))
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Queue:',repr(ex))

async def main_loop_task():
    task = asyncio.get_running_loop().create_task(mp_queue_wait())
    for i in range(3):
        print(i, os.times())
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await task
    print(repr(task))

asyncio.run(main_loop_task())
```

Whose output is:

```
0 posix.times_result(user=0.41, system=0.04, children_user=0.0, children_system=0.0, elapsed=17208620.18)
Queue: Empty()
1 posix.times_result(user=0.41, system=0.04, children_user=0.0, children_system=0.0, elapsed=17208622.18)
2 posix.times_result(user=0.41, system=0.04, children_user=0.0, children_system=0.0, elapsed=17208623.18)
<Task finished coro=<mp_queue_wait() done,...> result=None>
```

So I am looking at [asyncio.loop.run_in_executor()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) as the next possible answer, however spawning an executor/thread just for this seems overkill...

Here is same test using the default executor:

```
async def mp_queue_wait():
    try:
        result = await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(None,mp_q.get,True,2)
    except Exception as ex:
        result = ex
    print('Queue:',repr(result))
    return result
```

And the (desired) result:

```
0 posix.times_result(user=0.36, system=0.02, children_user=0.0, children_system=0.0, elapsed=17210674.65)
1 posix.times_result(user=0.37, system=0.02, children_user=0.0, children_system=0.0, elapsed=17210675.65)
Queue: Empty()
2 posix.times_result(user=0.37, system=0.02, children_user=0.0, children_system=0.0, elapsed=17210676.66)
<Task finished coro=<mp_queue_wait() done, defined at /home/apozuelo/Documents/5G_SBA/Tera5G/services/db.py:211> result=Empty()>
```

Comment: `run_in_executor` doesn't **spawn** a new executor or thread, it uses the existing executor to hand off the work to its thread pool. An executor maintains a pool of workers precisely so that submitting a task be as cheap as possible.

Comment: I mean: For tracking N queues like this you need N executor threads.

Comment: That's correct. If you plan to await on many queues in parallel, you might want to have an executor for that purpose, configured to spawn `N` threads. There are other problems with `run_in_executor`, such as that it doesn't respond to cancellation.

Comment: Unfortunately, "All threads enqueued to ThreadPoolExecutor will be joined before the interpreter can exit. Note that the exit handler which does this is executed before any exit handlers added using atexit. This means exceptions in the main thread must be caught and handled in order to signal threads to exit gracefully. For this reason, it is  recommended that ThreadPoolExecutor not be used for long-running tasks."

Answer (score 1):

This comes bit late, but.

You need to create an async wrapper around the `mp.JoinableQueue()` since both `get()`and `put()` block the whole process (GIL).

There are two approaches for this:

1. Use threads
2. Use `asyncio.sleep()` and `get_nowait()`, `put_nowait()` methods.

I chose the option 2 since it is easy.

```
from queue import Queue, Full, Empty
from typing import Any, Generic, TypeVar
from asyncio import sleep

T= TypeVar('T')

class AsyncQueue(Generic[T]):
    """Async wrapper for queue.Queue"""

    SLEEP: float = 0.01

    def __init__(self, queue: Queue[T]):
        self._Q : Queue[T] = queue


    async def get(self) -> T:
        while True:
            try:
                return self._Q.get_nowait()
            except Empty:
                await sleep(self.SLEEP)
    

    async def put(self, item: T) -> None:       
        while True:
            try:
                self._Q.put_nowait(item)
                return None
            except Full:
                await sleep(self.SLEEP)


    def task_done(self) -> None:
        self._Q.task_done()
        return None
```

Comment: Interesting solution. For clarity, I would have added `async_queue = AsyncQueue(Queue())`, kept the `asyncio.sleep()` (to avoid confusion with `time.sleep()`) and make the `SLEEP` constant an optional parameter.

Comment: good points, both. I have realized how my habit of importing functions directly can cause confusion since many packages have functions with the same basenames.